# Windows 10 Audio input to programs broken

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, audio, drivers

Recently my audio input, from USB headset and USB guitar cable have stopped working. Going into Windows 'Sounds' and enabling 'Listen to this device' outputs the audio as expected; the problem is not with the devices. However, as soon as I try to use them with any other program, discord, for example, no audio input is detected by discord.

I have tried everything I can think of and some suggestions from Googling around;

- Updating everything - windows, drivers, all related software
- Rolling windows back to the last build
- Trying different USB ports
- Reinstalling drivers and software
- Running Windows troubleshooters
- Playing with device properties settings

But nothing seems to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings > Privacy > Microphone > Let apps use my microphone.

New privacy "feature" in the 2018 Spring update, which of course is off by default.